# How to export column values for input into contour List using modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I am relatively new to modelbuilder and I need some help with attribute querying and exporting.

I am using modelbuilder in arcgis 10.2 and I need to find out if there is a way of exporting the values within a specific column of a layers attribute table for subsequent input into the contour list tool in arcgis?

Answer (score 2):

I can get you there, bear in mind there may be easier ways.

A. Create and save this model, it will act as a submodel or nested model:
[image: SubModel]

Model purpose: To iterate over each contour value and collect them into a list which will be used as input for the Contour List tool in the main model.

Notes:

- Iterate Field Values is to be found in the Insert menu, under Iterators.
- For the iterator, choose the field with contour values and **specify Double under Data Type**. This is important because Contour List accepts floating points.
- Collect Values is found in the Insert menu, under Model Only Tools.
- **Right click Output Values and click Model Parameter**. We do this because the output of this model will be used as the input for the main model.

B. Create this model, the main model:

[image: Main Model]

Notes:

- In order to get the SubModel in there, simply drag your saved sub model into this main model, as you would with any tool.